# JavaScript json for-loop Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, syntax-error

**I am trying to eliminate a chunk of variables:**

```
var security  = [
      { name:   'X-Powered-By',
        option: '' }
    , { name:   'x-frame-options',
        option: file.get('headers.xFrameOptions') }
    , { name:   'X-XSS-Protection',
        option: file.get('headers.xXSSProtection') }
    , { // AND SO ON...}
    ]
```

That is looped with:

```
// Add Content Security Rules to the header
for(var i = 0; i < security.length; i++) {
  res.setHeader(security[i].name, security[i].option);
}
```

In order to eliminate all those variables, I am trying to edit the `for-loop` in the following way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < file.get('headers.length; i++') {
  res.setHeader(headers[i].name);
}
```

I am getting a syntax error and I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.  An example would be very appreciated.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting in your post, it should show you the misplaced quote.

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < file.get('headers.length'); i++)` Watch your quotes.

Comment: @CelticParser Don't you have an error here: `for(var i = 0; i < file.get('headers.length; i++')`? May be you meant `for(var i = 0; i < file.get('headers.length'); i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have problems with your closing brackets and quotes, should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < file.get('headers.length') ; i++) {
  res.setHeader(headers[i].name);
}
```